# Github API Rate Limit Exceeded when it used to work

Tags: authentication, github, token, carthage

I'm running the following in an Azure pipeline:

```
GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN=$(token) carthage update --platform iOS
```

Up until today, passing a Personal Access Token in this way worked well to avoid the `API rate limit exceeded` message, but suddenly I'm getting this error:

> API rate limit exceeded for 199.19.85.33. (But here's the good news: Authenticated requests get a higher rate limit. Check out the documentation for more details.

My request *is* authenticated. Has something changed regarding Github tokens and/or Carthage? I'm using Carthage 0.34.0.

Comment: I have the same issue on GitHub Actions with exactly the SAME IP ADDRESS. No solution, unfortunately, but here is my theory:  Carthages polling specs. Specs located on GitHub. GitHub located on Azure. Whenever someone builds the Carthage project on GitHub Actions or Azure it all goes in the one basket because there is one public IP address.

Comment: BTW, caching carthages solve the problem